# Dynamic Structures And Storing Data without stdlib.h

Tags: c, data-structures

I have tried using Google, but not really sure how to phrase my search to get relevant results. The programming language is C. I was given a (homework) assignment which requires reading a text file and outputting the unique words in the text file. The restriction is that the only allowable import is `<stdio.h>`. So, is there a way to use dynamic structures without using `<stdlib.h>`? Would it be necessary to define those dynamic structures on my own? If this has already been addressed on Stack Overflow, then please point me to the question.

Clarification was provided today that the allowable imports now include `<stdlib.h>` as well as (though not necessary or desirable) the use of `<string.h>`, which in turn makes this problem easier (and I am tempted to say trivial).

Comment: Well... the short answer you can attempt it with a simple 2D array up to the limits of your stack space. The longest word in the Unabridged Dictionary (non-medical)  is 29-characters. So even the longest word  can be stored in an array of 30-`char`. (to include the *nul-terminator*). With a 1-meg stack, that is an array of roughly 33,000 words. You can simply keep an word-count, read a word, loop over your array of `seen` words to see if it is already there. If so, read next word, repeat. If it isn't there, increment word-count and add the word to the array.

Comment: Doesn't that assume that the text file does not have a word count that exceeds the size of the stack?

Comment: Indeed it does. If you have a file that has more than 33,000 unique words -- that's one hell-of-a file `:)`

Comment: There are *two* meanings for unique - *unique* and *distinct* - which one did the assignment mean?

Comment: Now there is one answer that does "unique" and another that does "distinct".

Comment: Use a VLA `fseek(..., end); long sz = ftell(in_file); char text[sz]; rewind(in_file) fread(...)` --> Now you have a dynamically sized array with only `stdio.h`.  Hope the file is not too big.  Could you post what you have tried?

Comment: @chux then after that need another loop to count the number of words to declare the pointer array to point to the individual words... and then loop again over them and put the pointers into the array...

Comment: ... or write a for loop that scans the words in the array and a `strcmp` that considers only alphabetic characters or sth...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Perhaps one pass word count --> sz, hash VLA[sz], 2nd pass compute hash/offset.  No need to store the "words" as the file does that already for  collision resolution.  Looks interesting to code, just wish there was some code in the original post.  O(n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is telling that you couldn't find anything with Google. Assignments with completely arbitrary restrictions are **idiotic**. The assignment tells something profound about the quality of the course and the instructor. There is more to be learnt from an assignment that *requires* the use of `realloc` and other standard library functions.

You don't need a data structure, only a large enough 2-dimensional char array - you must know at *compile time* how long words you're going to have *and* how many of them are there going to be at most; or you need to read the file once and then you're going to allocate a two-dimensional variable-length array on the stack (and possibly blow the stack), reset the file pointer and read the file again into that array...

Then you read the words into it using `fgets`, loop over the words using 2 nested `for` loops and comparing the first and second strings together (of course you'd skip if both outer and inner loop are at the same index) - if you don't find a match in the inner loop, you'll print the word.

Doing the assignment this way doesn't teach anything useful about programming, but the only standard library routine you need replicate yourself is `strcmp` and at least you'll save your energy for something useful instead.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I am going to attempt to implement this today and will update the question accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: @user3727648 please do ask a *new* question instead if the system allows so.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to code dynamic data structures in c using only stdio.h. That may be one of the reasons your teacher restricted you to using just stdio.h--they didn't want you going down the rabbit hole of trying to make a linked list or something in which to store unique words.

However, if you think about it, you don't need a dynamic data structure. Here's something to try: (1) make a copy of your source file. (2) declare a results text file to store your results. (3) Copy the first word in your source file to the results file. Then run through your **source file** and delete every copy of that word. Now there can't be any duplicates of that word. Then move on to the next word and copy and delete.

When you're done, your source file should be empty (thus the reason for the backup) and your results file should have one copy of every unique word from the original source file.

The benefit of this approach is that it doesn't require you to know (or guess) the size of the initial source file.

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that it is an O(N²) algorithm — and it isn't clear whether you're planning to modify the original file, or a copy of it, or what.  Hacking the original file probably isn't a good idea — it'll be all but empty after processing the last word.

Comment: Yes and No...First, efficiency wasn't part of the assignment, but more importantly, this is English where the same word gets used over and over. In my solution, each pass will have less words to scan than the pass before it due to deletions. For example, Wolfram|Alpha says that while there are ~30,000 words in Hamlet--the longest Shakespearean play--there are **only 4,620 unique words**, so that's actually only 4620 passes for what is basically a novella. So here's the real question, how long will it take a program coded in C to loop 4,600 times across a rapidly shrinking file. I bet not long.

Comment: Agreed on efficiency not being part of the assignment. This is a mid-level undergraduate course that is suppose to provide an overview of several programming languages (Python, C, C++, etc.) and we spend ~2 - 2.5 weeks on each language. There is a large jump in the knowledge provided by the notes and the expectations for assignments, but particularly this assignment. Just a little background/context

Answer (score 1):

Agreed on the points above on "exercises with arbitrary constraints" mostly being used to illustrate a lecturers favorite pet peeve.

However, if you are allowed to be naive you could do what others have said and assume a maximum size for your array of unique strings and use a simple buffer. I wrote a little stub illustrating what I was thinking. However, it is shared with the disclaimer that I am not a "real programmer", with all the bad habits and knowledge-gaps that follows...
I have obviously also ignored the topics of reading the file and filtering unique words.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                       // scanf, printf, etc.
#include <string.h>               // strcpy, strlen (only for convenience here)

#define NUM_STRINGS 1024                           // maximum number of strings
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 32      // maximum length of a string (in fixed buffer)


char fixed_buff[NUM_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_SIZE];
char * buff[NUM_STRINGS]; // <-- Will only work for string literals OR
                          // if the strings that populates the buffer
                          // are stored in a separate location and the
                          // buffer refers to the permanent location.

/**
 * Fixed length of buffer (NUM_STRINGS) and max item length (MAX_STRING_SIZE)
 */
void example_1(char strings[][MAX_STRING_SIZE] )
{
  // Note: terminates when first item in the current string is '\0'
  //       this may be a bad idea(?)
  for(size_t i = 0; *strings[i] != '\0'; i++)
    printf("strings[%ld] : %s (length %ld)\n", i, strings[i], strlen(strings[i]));
}


/**
 * Fixed length of buffer (NUM_STRINGS), but arbitrary item length
 */
void example_2(char * strings[])
{
  // Note: Terminating on reaching a NULL pointer as the number of strings is
  //       "unknown".
  for(size_t i = 0; strings[i] != NULL; i++)
    printf("strings[%ld] : %s (length %ld)\n", i, strings[i], strlen(strings[i]));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  // Populate buffers
  strncpy(fixed_buff[0], "foo", MAX_STRING_SIZE - 1);
  strncpy(fixed_buff[1], "bar", MAX_STRING_SIZE - 1);

  buff[0] = "mon";
  buff[1] = "ami";

  // Run examples
  example_1(fixed_buff);
  example_2(buff);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should be clear that `buf` will only work with strings that are *string literals* or have independent storage somewhere other than a buffer used to read from a file. Also with `" I was given a (homework)..."` questions, you generally want to limit the amount of code given (which you have made a reasonable attempt at)

Comment: Everything else *besides* `<stdio.h>` was forbidden, including `<string.h>`.

Comment: Very good point about the string literals David, I was thinking about different alternatives he could use and it slipped my mind.

Antti, you are principally absolutely correct. However, I just wanted to convey a couple of possible approaches and the use of `string.h` is not required for the concept to apply.